# Is there any way to fetch only date from new date() function without time

Tags: angularjs

Suppose this one is the value which I have Mon Jul 04 2016 18:12:03 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) and I want result as Jul-04-2016. How can I do this in Angular JS.

Comment: you can use 'date' filter..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a snippet working:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.data = new Date();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>      
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  Date without format: <span ng-bind="data"></span>
  <hr/ >
  Date with format ("MMM-dd-y"): <span ng-bind="data | date: 'MMM-dd-y'"></span>
</body>

</html>
```

You can check all the formats provided by date API [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date).

Answer (score 1):

Use [$filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date):

```
$scope.date = $filter('date')(
      new Date('Mon Jul 04 2016 18:12:03 GMT+0530'), 'MMM-dd-y'
);
//Output July-04-2016
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yzdwza20/)